# Sqlite: how to delete rows that contain null/empty strings

Tags: sql, sqlite

First of all thanks for your help.
I do an learning SQL, so I need some help.

I have a Sqlite database in which some fields in a certain column contains nothing or string of spaces.

Please How do I delete the rows containing nothing (or string of spaces) from the database?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IS NULL OR trim(myColumn) = '';
```

The `trim()` is necessary so that strings containing just whitespace are collapsed to an empty string.

Comment: Could you share your test data? That works fine for me with SQLite.

Comment: of course. But I have to send you the db via email because I am behind a firewall

Comment: sqlite kungfu plus one, it worked with `DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IS null`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE
  (filed IS NULL OR filed  = '')
```

Multiple Column:

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE
  (filed IS NULL OR filed  = '')
  AND (filed2 IS NULL OR filed2 = '')
  AND (filed3 IS NULL OR filed2 = '')
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer will work for any SQL database:

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_COLUMN IS NULL
OR TRIM(MY_COLUMN) = ''
```

See this WHERE clause [working in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e2518/3)

Comment: This doesn't detect the "string of spaces" case.

Comment: Nope, I've just tested with SQLite. A string of spaces does not match `''`.

Comment: @GrahamBorland I just tested it too. and was surprised to find it needed the TRIM()... answer edited

Answer (score 1):

DELETE FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_COLUMN IS NULL
OR MY_COLUMN like ''